# testID does not work for rightButtons in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

How can I test a button in the react-native-navigation's navigatorButtons, I have added testID for rightButtons but the test case fails while testing the toBeVisible(). Also I don't find a way to check the test cases for 'back' and 'sideMenu' default buttons.

```
const rightButtons = [
  { id: 'add', icon: iconsMap['add'], testID:'AddButton', },
  { id: 'list', icon: iconsMap['list'], testID:'ListButton', }
]
```